# why if else or nested if else are called single statement in C

Tags: c

Question from a beginner level C programmer:

```
if (exp)
    doX; 
else
    doY;
```

Semicolons are statement separators, then I am confused how if .. else or nested if.. else   are called single statement??

Answer (score 6):

In C, there are statements that contain other statements -- such statements are not terminated by a semicolon. An `if` statement is a *selection statement* that can *contain* one or two statements (that may in turn be *compound statements* -- curly brace blocks containing any number of statements), while itself being a single statement. An `if` statement is considered a single statement because it can be placed wherever a statement can occur.

Consider expressions: `1` is an expression, but so is `1+1` and so is `(1+(1+1)*(1-1))/1*(1%1)` ... that's one expression, containing other expressions.

Or think of a political division. For instance, the United States is a political division, but it contains states, which are political divisions, and states contain counties which contain cities ... all political divisions.

Edit: In regard to a question you asked in a comment ... there is no "else statement". Rather, an `if` statement has an optional else part:

```
if (condition) statement1 [else statement2]
```

The semicolons in your example terminate the inner statements; no semicolon is required to end the `if` statement as a whole. For example,

```
if (exp)
{ do1(); do2(); do3(); }    // statement1
else
{ do4(); do5(); }           // statement2
// no semicolon ending if statement
```

Here, statement1 and statement2 are blocks, which aren't terminated by semicolons, just as the `if` statement as a whole isn't terminated by a semicolon.

Edit in response to the question below:
The *exact* definition of a single statement is given in the C standard and is quite complex because it entails nearly the entire C grammar ... I'm trying to give a more conceptual overview. A statement is an executable component of the program that does not have a value (as opposed to expressions, which do have a value). Generally, statements are either non-compound statements that end in a semicolon, such as

```
x = 5;
```

or

```
return;
```

... or they are compounded statements that do not end in a semicolon, although they may appear to if their last component does, e.g.,

```
while (1)
    do_something();
```

or

```
while (1) {
    do_something();
}
```

Clearly, neither of those semicolons ends the while statement, they end the inner statements.

Comment: useful info. can you pls tell me exact definition of a single statement??

Comment: @user2674229 You can best thank people at SO for providing a satisfactory answer to your questions by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The semicolon terminates the statement processed in the `if()` clause, not the `if` it self. If you use braces it looks like this:

```
 if(1)
 {
     do_true_branch();   <== ';' terminates the statement
 }
 else
 {
     do_false_branch();   <== ';' terminates the statement
 }
```

If you only have one statement, you can ommit the braces, but the ';' is still needed for the statement.

Answer (score 3):

Both `if` and `else` will only find the next statement, including a block.

First, a block is a statement:

C11 6.8 Statements and blocks

> A block allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped into one syntactic unit.
>   The initializers of objects that have automatic storage duration, and the variable length
>   array declarators of ordinary identifiers with block scope, are evaluated and the values are stored in the objects (including storing an indeterminate value in objects without an
>   initializer) each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution, as if it were a statement, and within each declaration in the order that declarators appear.

Now Let's see how C defines a selection statement(i.e, `if`&`else` and `switch` statement) using the concept of block:

C11 6.8.4 Selection statements

> A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its
>   enclosing block. Each associated sub statement is also a block whose scope is a strict
>   subset of the scope of the selection statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are allowed to omit the `{}` providing the the if block or else block have only one statement.

Thus the C people have call this idiom a if single statement.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the `if` is called a single statement.

Comment: else is n't a separate statement?? as a semicolon is at the end of if statement..that's my confusion.

Comment: Don't be fool by the naming here. `if` can have one statement.  like the `else` and `else` always follow a `if`. Single statement here only mean that the if or the else have one statement. If an `if` and an `else` have one statement you have a total of 2 statements but you can call it a single statement if/else because of the `{}` omission.

Comment: To say that you're allowed to omit `{}` sounds as if the `if` statement specifically expects compound statements. That is not true as witnessed by a C grammar: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#selection-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition)
{
...
...
}
```

can be placed where ever a statement like 
    int x = 5;
can be placed. else can not appear without an if. So together it is called a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

In this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh88ctk1.aspx) you can find the answer. The `if` is the *selection statement* which takes a statement or compound statement as its body. Or two if you also use the `else` part.

When you supply a [compound statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce4b8s02.aspx) (in the curly braces), you don't need an extra semicolon.

Answer (score -5):

If you start with C just try to forget that it is possible and choose:

```
if (exp) {
  doX; 
} else {
  doY;
}
```

just to avoid a lot of errors in your future.

---

People ask: **Why does this answer the question?**

It answers it in a way that an awful lot of errors show up because the answer seems to be that obvious to most C programmers. Folowing errors are not of *theoretical* nature.

```
if(exp) dox; doy;
```

or

```
if(exp)
  dox;
  doy;
```

or

```
if(exp) dox;
  doy;
```

code. Thats not theretically. So I advice myself to insert {} as often as my brain allows me to, just to avoid those kind of errors. It is just to hard to find them later on.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: "People ask: Why does this answer the question?" -- No, no one asked that. nico rhetorically asked "how" it answers the question ... the point being that it doesn't answer the question *at all*. I hope that, now that you've been at SO for a while, you've learned what an answer is. You might want to either give one here or delete this and regain some rep.